Does the definition of a syllable as a unit of planning disambiguate syllable division in some cases?
I think ancient Greek grammarians were the first to try to systematically investigate the division of syllables, and they were trying both to prescribe rules for dividing words at the end of a written line and to explain the moraic structure of poetry that predated their writing system. Reasonable people could then disagree on cases such as τίκ-τω versus τί-κτω.
Looking for a modern scientific discussion of this, I found this web page: https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/courses/spsci/iss/week7.php (I think the author is Mark Huckvale, but there is no clear byline.) He offers the tantalizing statement that a syllable is a unit of planning, presenting a picture according to which the speech-producing organs are a coupled set of masses with inertia and friction. It makes sense to me that for such a physical system, the brain would have to plan ahead in order to articulate speech. What is less clear to me is that this provides some way to objectively define syllables, in the absence of acoustically marked boundaries that resolve the question.
Does the definition of a syllable as a unit of planning disambiguate syllable division in some cases? For example, could we say based on this definition whether τίκτω is really to be divided one way or the other?

I find the paper very interesting but I can't get my head around a syllable being "|a unit of planning". When one fully articulates words in a sentence versus squishing certain sounds together in connected speech, how is that done "in advance". To me, it's more like an acoustic database of recombinant sounds.

Problematic, as it invokes another process, “planning”, as the solution to a difficult problem that is hard to describe and fix with enough certainty to be really helpful.
The effect of “planning” is very different between highly frequent and conventionalised words and rarer words, or between highly probable words (in a given context) and more unexpected words (in a given context). The expected or frequent words are pronounced differently from the less expected ones, and this effect can be tested by asking probands to read sentences with the words occurring in contexts where they are more or less expected.
It is not at all clear whether to ascribe these effects to “planning” or to describe them as an effect of managing the information capacitiy of a noisy channel.

proband is a medical term in US English. Do you mean survey respondents?
